# Android Gestures Not Being Recognized

Tags: android, gesture, gesture-recognition, gestures

I'm trying to use gesture builder to recieve up/down and left/right gestures on my app. I followed the guide here (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html) and it seems to work but isn't quite responding the the gestures correct. It's showing left and right on the overlay in bright yellow (gesture found) but when `Toast` creates the pop-up to show the name of gesture recognised it's showing that right/up/down are all recognised or left/up/down are. Also it's doesn't recognise actual swipes up and down as valid gestures (faded out yellow on Overlay).

I've tried re-building the Gesture library using the Gesture Builder several times in case there was an error there but there doesn't seem to be.

The code being used is as per that above link.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gTap  = new GestureDetector(this,(android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener) this);

    //Remove title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //Define textView
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
    View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
    gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

    gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if (!gestureLib.load()) {
      finish();
    }
    setContentView(gestureOverlayView);


    //Load font file
    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/optima.ttf"); 

    //Set various textViews to font
    textView1.setTypeface(type);
    textView2.setTypeface(type);
    textView3.setTypeface(type);
    textView4.setTypeface(type);

    prevPass = "Memorable";

}


public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
  ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);
  for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
    if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
      Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804313/vertical-top-to-bottom-line-gesture-detector/22807326#22807326), Add this to your code.

```
GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    gestures.setGestureStrokeAngleThreshold( 90.0f);
```

[Here](https://github.com/manangandhi7/Gesture-Builder) is complete code for Gesture Builder application. You can try that too.