# Vertical top to bottom line gesture detector

Tags: android

I used the https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davemac327.gesture.tool&hl=en

gesture tool and noticed that for a line which is top to bottom vertically is not able to detect as i am using the generated gesture file in my code as follows but not able to detect the vertical top to bottom line gesture detection

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.Prediction;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GesturesActivity extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {
    private GestureLibrary mLibrary;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!mLibrary.load()) {
            finish();
        }

        GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
    }

    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
        String data="";
        for (int i = 0; i < predictions.size(); i++) {
            data=data+ "=="+predictions.get(i).name;

        }

        // We want at least one prediction
        if (predictions.size() > 0) {
            Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
            // We want at least some confidence in the result
            if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
                // Show the spell
                Toast.makeText(this,data+ "  "+ prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

please suggest how to perform a vertical top to bottom vertical gesture detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was problem with the above code which i solved by introducing

```
   GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestures.setGestureStrokeAngleThreshold( 90.0f);
```

As the default value of the angle threashold is 40.0f because of which simple vertical gestures would be skipped so changed it to 90.0f, so finally setting the GestureStrokeAngleThreshold to a value closer to 90.0f works fine